How to group only only the columns having some condition
Here is my data grid code for preimium. I have a field boolean on the basis of that boolean field I want to show the expand group otherwise want to show it inline without grouping.
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
  apiRef,
  initialState: {
    sorting: {
      sortModel: [{ field: "__row_group_by_columns_group__", sort: "asc" }],
    },
    rowGrouping: {
      model: ["myGroupingField"],
    },
  },
});
<DataGridPremium
    rows={data}
    columns={[
        { field: 'myGroupingField', align: 'left', headerName: 'Group Id', width: 180, headerAlign: 'left' }
    ]}
    apiRef={apiRef}
    loading={loading}
    disableRowSelectionOnClick
    initialState={initialState}
    slots={{ toolbar: CustomToolbarWithButton }}
/>

Please help me here

If I understood your question then this might get you want you need
import React from 'react';
import { useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
import { useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

const YourComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  // Determine if grouping is enabled based on your boolean field
  const isGroupingEnabled = data.some(row => row.booleanField);

  // Set initialState based on whether grouping is enabled or not
  const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
    apiRef,
    initialState: {
      sorting: {
        sortModel: [{ field: '__row_group_by_columns_group__', sort: 'asc' }],
      },
      rowGrouping: {
        model: isGroupingEnabled ? ['myGroupingField'] : [], // Conditionally include grouping
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <DataGridPremium
      rows={data}
      columns={[
        { field: 'myGroupingField', align: 'left', headerName: 'Group Id', width: 180, headerAlign: 'left' }
      ]}
      apiRef={apiRef}
      loading={loading}
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
      initialState={initialState}
      slots={{ toolbar: CustomToolbarWithButton }}
    />
  );
};

export default YourComponent;


yes you understood it correctly however it is not working. const isGroupingEnabled = data.some(row => row.booleanField) how we can set the row grouping based on the above isGroupingEnabled as it is an array field?

What's the name of your Boolean field? Did you update my code to reflect your name?

isExpand is the field name
